# Replace values in XML string with less than descriptive path

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have a very large xml field inside of a SQL Database that I have to edit regularly.  I wrote the following Query to change that code which was easy following the xml path to get to what needed changed.

However I found more things further down in SQL that needs altered and I can not figure out the xml path to edit to make that change.

I've been utilizing the following Query to change just the username

```
DECLARE @config_xml2 xml
select @config_xml2 = configuration_xml from tblDatafeed where datafeed_name = 'DatafeedName' update tbldatafeed
set configuration_xml.modify('replace value of (//*:NetworkCredentialWrapper/@UserName)[1] with sql:variable("@LOGIN")') where datafeed_name ='DataFeedName'
```

Which is used to change the Username in the following:

```
  <Tokens>
    <Token name="DataFileDirectoryName" />
    <Token name="DataFileName" />
    <Token name="DataFileExtension" />
    <Token name="LastRunTime" />
    <Token name="LastFileProcessed" />
  </Tokens>
  <Transporter>
    <transporters:WebServiceTransportActivity xmlns:transporters="clr-namespace:ArcherTech.DataFeed.Activities.Transporters;assembly=ArcherTech.DataFeed" xmlns:out="clr-namespace:ArcherTech.DataFeed;assembly=ArcherTech.DataFeed" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:compModel="clr-namespace:ArcherTech.DataFeed.ComponentModel;assembly=ArcherTech.DataFeed" xmlns:channel="clr-namespace:ArcherTech.DataFeed.Engine.Channel;assembly=ArcherTech.DataFeed" xmlns:engine="clr-namespace:ArcherTech.DataFeed.Engine;assembly=ArcherTech.DataFeed" xmlns:kernel="clr-namespace:ArcherTech.Kernel.Channel;assembly=ArcherTech.Kernel" xmlns="clr-namespace:ArcherTech.DataFeed;assembly=ArcherTech.DataFeed" xmlns:schema="clr-namespace:System.Xml.Schema;assembly=System.Xml" xmlns:xmlLinq="clr-namespace:System.Xml.Linq;assembly=System.Xml" xmlns:domain="clr-namespace:ArcherTech.Common.Domain;assembly=ArcherTech.Common" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" x:Key="transportActivity" SearchType="ReportId" Uri="Type URL Here" RecordsPerFile="100" ReportID="" UseWindowsAuth="false" IsWindowsAuthSpecific="false" WindowsAuthUserName="" WindowsAuthPassword="" WindowsAuthDomain="" ProxyName="" ProxyPort="" ProxyUsername="" ProxyPassword="" ProxyDomain="" IsProxyActive="False" ProxyOption="None" InstanceName="Type Instance Name Here" TempFileOnSuccessAction="DoNothing" TempFileOnSuccessRenameString="" TempFileOnErrorAction="DoNothing" TempFileOnErrorRenameString="" Transform="{engine:DataFeedBinding Path=Transform}" SessionContext="{engine:DataFeedBinding Path=Session}">
      <transporters:ArcherWebServiceTransportActivity.Credentials>
        <NetworkCredentialWrapper UserName="" />
      </transporters:ArcherWebServiceTransportActivity.Credentials>
    </transporters:ArcherWebServiceTransportActivity>
  </Transporter>
  <Iterator>
    <XmlIterator>
```

But now I need to alter a string that a lot more complex and I am not sure my xml location is right.  I have tried using //*NewSourceName1/@Calculation but it doesnt seem work:

Line of code Here I am trying to edit:

```
 &lt;xs:element name="NewSourceName1" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Dashboard_Instance_Name" c:Calculation="=STATIC(&amp;quot;MYSTRINGOFTEXTHERE&amp;quot;)" dfm:SimpleFieldType="StaticText" /&gt;
```

Full xml it falls under

```
  <Action>
    <DataTransfer TargetType="Application" TargetLevel="20595ffc-afd5-4d34-babb-c8fa67c610ee" DisableValidation="true" PreValidate="false" InsertRecords="true" UpdateRecords="false" SyncAction="None" SyncFlagField="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" SyncFlagValue="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
      <Source>
        <Schema>&lt;Schemas&gt;
&lt;xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.archer-tech.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dfm="http://schemas.archer-tech.com/2009/xaml/datafeed" xmlns:c="http://archertech.com/ChannelFramework/Extensions" dfm:ComplexFieldType="None"&gt;
  &lt;xs:element name="ArcherRecords" nillable="true"&gt;
    &lt;xs:complexType&gt;
      &lt;xs:sequence&gt;
        &lt;xs:element name="ArcherRecord" nillable="true" c:Name="ArcherRecord" dfm:ComplexFieldType="None" maxOccurs="unbounded"&gt;
          &lt;xs:complexType&gt;
            &lt;xs:sequence&gt;
              &lt;xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Name" /&gt;
              &lt;xs:element name="Container_Type" nillable="true" c:Name="Container_Type"&gt;
                &lt;xs:complexType&gt;
                  &lt;xs:sequence&gt;
                    &lt;xs:element name="Item" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Item" /&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:sequence&gt;
                &lt;/xs:complexType&gt;
              &lt;/xs:element&gt;
              &lt;xs:element name="Path" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Path" /&gt;
              &lt;xs:element name="Abbreviation_Unique_Key" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Abbreviation_Unique_Key" /&gt;
              &lt;xs:element name="Container_Owner" nillable="true" c:Name="Container_Owner"&gt;
                &lt;xs:complexType&gt;
                  &lt;xs:sequence&gt;
                    &lt;xs:element name="Item" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Item" /&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:sequence&gt;
                &lt;/xs:complexType&gt;
              &lt;/xs:element&gt;

              &lt;xs:element name="Send_Upstream" nillable="true" c:Name="Send_Upstream"&gt;
                &lt;xs:complexType&gt;
                  &lt;xs:sequence&gt;
                    &lt;xs:element name="Item" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Item" /&gt;
                  &lt;/xs:sequence&gt;
                &lt;/xs:complexType&gt;
              &lt;/xs:element&gt;
              &lt;xs:element name="NewSourceName" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Iteration" c:Calculation="=IF(AND(HOUR(NOW())&amp;gt;=0,HOUR(NOW())&amp;lt;8), &amp;quot;ONE&amp;quot;,&amp;#xA;  IF(AND(HOUR(NOW())&amp;gt;=8,HOUR(NOW())&amp;lt;16), &amp;quot;TWO&amp;quot;, &amp;quot;THREE&amp;quot;))" dfm:SimpleFieldType="CalculatedField" /&gt;
              &lt;xs:element name="NewSourceName1" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Dashboard_Instance_Name" c:Calculation="=STATIC(&amp;quot;MyTextHere&amp;quot;)" dfm:SimpleFieldType="StaticText" /&gt;
              &lt;xs:element name="NewSourceName2" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Date_Created" c:Calculation="=DATEFORMAT(TODAY(), &amp;quot;MM/dd/yyyy&amp;quot;)" dfm:SimpleFieldType="CalculatedField" /&gt;
              &lt;xs:element name="NewSourceName3" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Created_By" c:Calculation="=STATIC(&amp;quot;Local Dashboard&amp;quot;)" dfm:SimpleFieldType="StaticText" /&gt;
            &lt;/xs:sequence&gt;
          &lt;/xs:complexType&gt;
        &lt;/xs:element&gt;
      &lt;/xs:sequence&gt;
    &lt;/xs:complexType&gt;
  &lt;/xs:element&gt;
&lt;/xs:schema&gt;
&lt;/Schemas&gt;</Schema>
      </Source>
```

Hopeful out come (Look for MYSTRINGOFTEXTHERE or if I could just edit all of =STATIC(&quot;MYSTRINGOFTEXTHERE&quot;)):

```
 &lt;xs:element name="NewSourceName1" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Dashboard_Instance_Name" c:Calculation="=STATIC(&amp;quot;MYSTRINGOFTEXTHERE&amp;quot;)" dfm:SimpleFieldType="StaticText" /&gt;
```

What I tried that didn't work

```
DECLARE @config_xml2 xml
select @config_xml2 = configuration_xml from tblDatafeed where datafeed_name = 'DatafeedName' update tbldatafeed
set configuration_xml.modify('replace value of (//*:NewSourceName1/@Calculation)[1] with sql:variable("@CoolVariableName")') where datafeed_name ='DataFeedName'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the XML is really looking like the one provided above, you should change its creation (if possible). Your XML ends at `</Schema>`. Everything in there is one chunk of (escpaed) string, it's a big `text()` node actually. Within this text you won't use XQuery or XPath... If you have to stick to this: You can read this typed 'nvarchar(max)' using `.value()` and **cast it to XML**. From there you might proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath expression was completely off, so I adjusted it.

In XML, there are only five built-in character entities: `&lt;, &gt;, &amp;, &quot; and &apos;` for <, >, &, " and ' respectively. I replaced them with their literals. Please try the following.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, configuration_xml XML);

INSERT INTO @tbl (configuration_xml)
VALUES 
(N'<Action>
    <DataTransfer TargetType="Application" TargetLevel="20595ffc-afd5-4d34-babb-c8fa67c610ee" DisableValidation="true" PreValidate="false" InsertRecords="true" UpdateRecords="false" SyncAction="None" SyncFlagField="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" SyncFlagValue="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
        <Source>
            <Schema>
                <Schemas>
                    <xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.archer-tech.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dfm="http://schemas.archer-tech.com/2009/xaml/datafeed" xmlns:c="http://archertech.com/ChannelFramework/Extensions" dfm:ComplexFieldType="None">
                        <xs:element name="ArcherRecords" nillable="true">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence>
                                    <xs:element name="ArcherRecord" nillable="true" c:Name="ArcherRecord" dfm:ComplexFieldType="None" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:sequence>
                                                <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Name" />
                                                <xs:element name="Container_Type" nillable="true" c:Name="Container_Type">
                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                        <xs:sequence>
                                                            <xs:element name="Item" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Item" />
                                                        </xs:sequence>
                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                </xs:element>
                                                <xs:element name="Path" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Path" />
                                                <xs:element name="Abbreviation_Unique_Key" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Abbreviation_Unique_Key" />
                                                <xs:element name="Container_Owner" nillable="true" c:Name="Container_Owner">
                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                        <xs:sequence>
                                                            <xs:element name="Item" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Item" />
                                                        </xs:sequence>
                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                </xs:element>

                                                <xs:element name="Send_Upstream" nillable="true" c:Name="Send_Upstream">
                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                        <xs:sequence>
                                                            <xs:element name="Item" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Item" />
                                                        </xs:sequence>
                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                </xs:element>
                                                <xs:element name="NewSourceName" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Iteration" c:Calculation="=IF(AND(HOUR(NOW())&amp;gt;=0,HOUR(NOW())&amp;lt;8), &amp;quot;ONE&amp;quot;,&amp;#xA;  IF(AND(HOUR(NOW())&amp;gt;=8,HOUR(NOW())&amp;lt;16), &amp;quot;TWO&amp;quot;, &amp;quot;THREE&amp;quot;))" dfm:SimpleFieldType="CalculatedField" />
                                                <xs:element name="NewSourceName1" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Dashboard_Instance_Name" c:Calculation="=STATIC(&amp;quot;MyTextHere&amp;quot;)" dfm:SimpleFieldType="StaticText" />
                                                <xs:element name="NewSourceName2" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Date_Created" c:Calculation="=DATEFORMAT(TODAY(), &amp;quot;MM/dd/yyyy&amp;quot;)" dfm:SimpleFieldType="CalculatedField" />
                                                <xs:element name="NewSourceName3" type="xs:string" nillable="true" c:Name="Created_By" c:Calculation="=STATIC(&amp;quot;Local Dashboard&amp;quot;)" dfm:SimpleFieldType="StaticText" />
                                            </xs:sequence>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:schema>
                </Schemas>
            </Schema>
        </Source>
    </DataTransfer>
</Action>');

DECLARE @CoolVariableName varchar(30) = 'Whatever Value'; 

UPDATE @tbl
SET configuration_xml.modify('replace value of (//xs:element[@name="NewSourceName1"]/@*:Calculation)[1] with sql:variable("@CoolVariableName")');

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: The problem here is I have multiple rows that have different values in them where each is not NewSourceName1.  and that text above it is not static but always different in each configuration-xml

Comment: @Nathan, there is no magical way to get to the right spot, element or attribute, in any XML structure. You always need to know its location and how to get to it via XPath expression.